# How To Identify Overlap Number Ranges Considering Range Type?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables TABLE1(List of Records) & TABLE2(My Number Ranges to Check)

How to identify overlap ranges/row(s) in TABLE2 considering TypeId ?

**OBJECTIVE**

```
RECORDS TABLE
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+
+     typeId      + tbl1_NumberFrom + tbl1_NumberTo     +
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+
+       1         +      1          +        5          +
+       1         +      8          +        10         +
+       1         +      15         +        20         +
+       2         +      4          +        7          +
+       2         +      9          +        10         +
+       2         +      11         +        20         +
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+

MY RANGES TABLE TO CHECK
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+
+      typeId     + My_NumberFrom   + My_NumberTo       +
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+
+      1          +      1          +        3          +
+      1          +      6          +        8          +
+      1          +      11         +        12         +
+      2          +      1          +        3          +
+      2          +      6          +        8          +
+      2          +      10         +        10         +
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+

REQUIRED RESULT AS FOLLOW:
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
+      typeId     + My_NumberFrom   + My_NumberTo       +   IsOverlapping   +
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
+      1          +      1          +        3          +        YES        +
+      2          +      1          +        3          +        NO         +
+      1          +      6          +        8          +        YES        +
+      2          +      6          +        8          +        YES        +
+      1          +      11         +        12         +        NO         +
+      2          +      10         +        10         +        YES        +
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

**FURTHER MORE,**

**SQL for above Tables**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#dbtable', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #dbtable; 
SELECT * INTO #dbtable FROM 
    (SELECT 1 typeId, 1 AS tbl1_NumberFrom, 5 AS tbl1_NumberTo
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 typeId, 8 AS tbl1_NumberFrom, 10 AS tbl1_NumberTo
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 typeId, 15 AS tbl1_NumberFrom, 20 AS tbl1_NumberTo 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 typeId, 4  AS tbl1_NumberFrom, 7 AS tbl1_NumberTo 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 typeId, 9 AS tbl1_NumberFrom, 10 AS tbl1_NumberTo 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 typeId, 11 AS tbl1_NumberFrom, 20 AS tbl1_NumberTo) 
AS dbTable

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#MyRanges', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #MyRanges; 
SELECT * INTO #MyRanges FROM 
    (SELECT 1 typeId, 1 AS myr_NumberFrom, 3 AS myr_NumberTo
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 typeId, 6 AS myr_NumberFrom, 8 AS myr_NumberTo 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 typeId, 11 AS myr_NumberFrom, 12 AS myr_NumberTo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 typeId, 1 AS My_NumberFrom, 3 AS myr_NumberTo
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 typeId, 6 AS myr_NumberFrom, 8 AS myr_NumberTo 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 typeId, 10 AS myr_NumberFrom, 10 AS myr_NumberTo)
AS MyList


SELECT * FROM #dbtable t
SELECT * FROM #MyRanges m
```

Kindly suggest,

Many Thanks !!

Comment: Shouldn't the last row (2-10-10) be YES? It overlaps with 2-9-10.

Comment: @NemanjaPerovic oh yes you are right.. modified the question thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.*,
CASE ISNULL(t.typeId,0) WHEN 0 THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS IsOverlapping   
 FROM #MyRanges m
LEFT OUTER JOIN #dbtable t
ON t.typeId = m.typeId
AND 
(t.tbl1_NumberFrom BETWEEN m.myr_NumberFrom AND m.myr_NumberTo
OR
t.tbl1_NumberTo BETWEEN m.myr_NumberFrom AND m.myr_NumberTo)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to check if two ranges overlap is to test if one starts before the other ends, while the other starts before the first ends.
Here is one way to do it in t-sql:

```
SELECT  typeId, 
        myr_NumberFrom, 
        myr_NumberTo,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM #dbtable t
            WHERE t.typeId = m.typeId
            AND tbl1_NumberFrom <= myr_NumberTo
            AND tbl1_NumberTo >= myr_NumberFrom
        ) THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END As IsOverlapping   
FROM #MyRanges m
```

Results:

```
typeId  myr_NumberFrom  myr_NumberTo    IsOverlap
1       1               3               Yes
1       6               8               Yes
1       11              12              No
2       1               3               No
2       6               8               Yes
2       10              10              Yes
```

Changed to a left join instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT  m.typeId, 
        myr_NumberFrom, 
        myr_NumberTo,
        CASE WHEN t.typeId IS NOT NULL THEN 
            'Yes'
        ELSE
            'No'
        END As IsOverlapping   
FROM #MyRanges m
LEFT JOIN #dbtable t ON m.typeId = t.typeId
                    AND myr_NumberFrom <= tbl1_NumberTo
                    AND myr_NumberTo >= tbl1_NumberFrom
```

Results are the same, live demo have been updated.

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/FVSQ97005)

Comment: isn't slow? while using select in case?

Comment: Sub queries might be slower then joins. It's easy to translate to a join if you want to...

Comment: There, now you have also a left join.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is almost the same as the answer on your other question.

There are four types of overlap. You need two conditions to find the overlap. The other answers are forgetting about overlapping type where myr_numberfrom < tbl1.numberfrom and myr_numberto > tbl1_numberto.

```
Select distinct m.typeId, m.Myr_NumberFrom,m.Myr_NumberTo, 
        case when t.tbl1_NumberFrom is null then 'No' else 'yes' end isOverlapping
from #MyRanges m
left join #dbtable t on m.typeId = t.typeId
                and (m.Myr_NumberFrom between t.tbl1_NumberFrom and t.tbl1_NumberTo
                or  t.tbl1_NumberFrom between m.Myr_NumberFrom and m.Myr_Numberto)
```